# Google Picker API - Error: idpifram_initialization_failed

Tags: google-picker

I have the following code
JS:

```js
var clientId = "236416465129-r17h1bb7qoen8qcs0v1ttrbtdaj8vp41.apps.googleusercontent.com";

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];

var pickerApiLoaded = false;
var oauthToken;

// Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
function loadPicker() {
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
    gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': onPickerApiLoad });
}

function onAuthApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
        },
        handleAuthResult);
}

function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="loadPicker();" value="Browse" />

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When press button Browse, the debug value that i get is **Error:idpifram_initialization_failed**

"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
Thanks to everyone for help